# Partition a Binary Tree into two tree such that the difference of their diameter is less than a specific value K

Tags: tree, dynamic-programming, graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Given a Binary Tree. We have to `remove an edge` and partition it into `two trees` such that the `difference of the diameter of the two new trees is less than a specified value K`.

I have a naive solution that picks `each edge` and checks for the condition that if by removing that edge we can obtain the solution or not (We can do this by using two `DFS/BFS` and calculate the diameter). This makes my solution O(n^2).

Can someone suggest me a better approach than mine?

I think we can use Dynamic Programing for this, But I am unable to visualize it.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough for each node to calculate height of tree below it. For leaf node it is 0, and for other nodes it is `max(height of children) + 1`. That is done with [tree post-order traversing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order).

<strike>Diameter of a binary tree is `height of left child + height of right child + 1`. For general trees it is `(sum of two max heights) + 1`.</strike>

Idea of algorithm is to start from a root and 'climb down' higher child, while checking difference between diameter of child's subtree and rest of a tree. That can be done with calculated heights.

**Update**

```
 root
 / \
L   R
```

In a tree, diameter pass through root node, or is completely in one of subtrees. With that:

`root.diameter = max(L.height + R.height + 2, L.diameter, R.diameter)`.

If we cut some edge, e.g. edge between `N` and `N.L`:

```
  root
  /  \
 ...  ...
  |
  N
 / \
L   R
```

`L` subtree has diameter by upper formula. Rest of tree has diameter

`max(R.height + length(R, root) + root.height, root.R.diameter, R.diameter)`.

Terms `R.height` and `R.diameter` depends on edge we want to check. Terms `root.height` and `root.R.diameter` are static while we are checking edges in `root.L` subtree (and vice verse). Term `length(R, root)` depends on edge depth from a root, which is easy to track.

With that it is possible to create method that recursively checks cuts on one subtree edges.

Comment: I have understood your approach, But After we climb down certain nodes, How to calculate the diameter of the upper half of the tree with only information about the max height of tree below it. I have a solution [here](http://ideone.com/LypbPw) But I am unsure of its correctness.

Comment: I agree with you. But you have to consider many cases like, longest path in the upper tree, best diameter in the upper subtree, diameter we get after joining the longest path(previous)and the longest path in the other child subtree(subtree which will be part of the upper tree after the cut), and the longest diameter in that subtree. And after checking all these, we have to update all the values accordingly. Please check if missed any case or I am wrong.

Comment: I think we have to keep track of the max diameter while climbing down which is generated in each of the cut. Have you taken care of this case?

Comment: @AdityaN.K No, I didn't :-/ Diameter of rest of a tree is max(R.diameter, N.parent.upper_diameter, R.diameter + N.parent.upper_diameter + 2), where upper_diameter is diameter of tree without subtree below N. That can be calculated while climbing down, since it depended on it's parent upper_diameter and N's sibling.